Why does "other" need a specific position in a sentence?
Take the sentence:

In the background we can see other three people who are watching the film.

I think it's wrong and it would be right to say:

In the background we can see three other  people who are watching the film.

Why does other work where it is in the second sentence and not in the first? Is there a rule here?

You need an article or something before other in the first, eg the other or another. Look at your rules for articles and determiners.

But in other cases you don't. Which is why an "answer" in a comment isn't good practice.

@Stuart  What you said was wholly true, and the Question was 'Why…'?

Nata gareeva asks a very important Question which even here, almost no-one will be able to Answer… any more than I can, which is why this is a Comment.
'… other three people…' does not work but '… another/any other/the other/those other and sometimes even 'that other…' works.
To me, it seems this is an extension of how and why 'determiners' are different from 'articles', which is obvious to no-one.

Yes, there is a rule: Cambridge Grammar, British Council.



Determiners
Numbers
Adjectives
nouns as modifiers
head




the
two
heavy
iron
gates


your

dark green, woollen

sweater



three
other

people



As "other" is an adjective and "three" a number, the latter comes before the former.

(Merriam Webster) other adjective


(OLD) three number


Isn't it possible to regard 'other' as a determiner here as it shows relation to domain rather than an inherent property of the referent of the noun? 'The three next people' / 'the three other people'.

I'm not sure that "the three next people" is to be preferred over "the next three people", at least without a specific context.

@EdwinAshworth In fact numbers can be considered to be determiners (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/number), and "other" can be considered to be a "general ordinal" (CoGEL); so, "other" is not an unlikely candidate for membership in the category of determiners. The criterion "domain vs inherent property" icertainly yields a positive answer.

@AndrewLeach I find correct, and that must be because of the frequency, only "the next three people". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+next+three+people%2Cthe+three+next+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3, https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+next+three+persons%2C+the+three+next+persons&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

@AndrewLeach In that phrase, "next" modifies "three", not "people" (it answers "which three people?").

Thanks LPH, and can you show how to apply that chart to the example in the Question?

@RobbieGoodwin  On the basis of the classification from Cambridge and the British Council, thas is straightforward, so I suppose that you are asking about the justification when "other" is not considered to be  an adjective but instead  a determiner. Things are not clear in that case, and the more so as further research lead me to things such as "(SOED) J. ROBERTSON St Bridget and other nine virgins." and "(CGEL) ex.: the three other examples. - the other three examples.".

@LPH  Perhaps but on the basis of every-day English, that's not straightforward.
I'm sorry I see 'other' only as a determiner. This is my first experience of it being described as an adjective and it leaves me wondering…
Do you really think '(anything) and other nine virgins…' could work in English?
Since they both contain articles, how d'you think 'the three other examples…' or 'the other three examples' could help here, please?
'… three other examples…' could work without its article, and I suspect you didn't mean that…

@RobbieGoodwin I can't tell you anything, I am, as you are, uncertain about many points.  The idea of "other" being a determiner seems to be a rather recent discovery of English grammarians (at any rate, Anglo-Saxon), and so there is still an important number of dictionaries that list that word as an adjective, although the SOED (1995) adds to the traditional label "adj" the note "in modern usage also classed as a_determiner_". // I"other nine …": that does not seem very usual, yet it is an SOED example. //  (1/2)

@RobbieGoodwin I hold as normal the most often found form "the other three examples"; I have tried to find a context for the other one but did come up with anything. Yet this example is given in a modern (and important grammar, CEGL).  // Plenty of "three other" (without "the") can be found): https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Reports_of_Cases_Argued_and_Determined_i/dRtHAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22three+other%22&dq=%22three+other%22&printsec=frontcover.  Here, "other" would mean "additional", and additional can't be an adjective, thereby something would make sense in that case. (2/2)

@LPH If you're not sure about 'other' being a determiner, consider 'a thing', 'the thing', 'this thing', 'that thing', 'another thing' and 'the other thing'.
I don't understand 'a rather recent discovery of English grammarians (at any rate, Anglo-Saxon)…' I think English grew out of Anglo-Saxon. Have you any dates?
My SOED is hiding in the attic so I, ask, what does '// I"other nine …" ' mean?
'The other three (people)…' and 'Three other people…' can both be correct… which is why there are plenty of 'three other' instances without 'the'.
'Other three people…' can't.
More…

@LPH   Further…  Does 'the other one…' refer to 'other three people'?
'Other' does mean CEGL's 'additional…'; sometimes 'different' but
taken literally, can replacing 'other' with 'additional' (or 'different') work?
Whether they're adjectives, determiners or what, 'additional', 'different' and 'other' are by themselves non-count items; they can be followed without inconsistency by generic 'people' but not by specified numbers of people.
'Other' can qualify 'people' but not 'three'.
'Three' can qualify either 'other' or 'people' or both.

@RobbieGoodwin The criterion for inherent characterisctic is negative, so the conclusion "determiner" is valid if there is only this one criterion; but then the same must be true for "additional", "supplementary_",  "extra",and so on; there is a catch; what's the point in defining a a finer category if its introduction in the system results in  a clash; personally, I can't see any other possibility of this definition vying with accepted notions than considering that those words are also determiners. For instance CGEL  tells us that "three is determiner in three books, but a  (1/3)

@RobbieGoodwin  modifier in "these three books". So it is not clear. // I meant "probably from England but not necessarily so, it could have been the USA or maybe Canada". // "the other three people" and "the three other people" would have the same meaning? // "Non-count should be apploied to nouns, only; if you mean "that can be used with non-count nouns", it appears to be at least partially wrong (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+additional+ten+*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3): "an additional ten days", for instance. (2/3)

@RobbieGoodwin To make matters worse, this is synonymous to "another ten days", where "another is a determiner. (3/3)

@LPH  I'm sorry to have led you astray, and why not look back to my original Comment?

@LPH How does that synonymity work? How many many examples can you cite, equating 'other' to another'?
If they're to be considered equal, in what context can you justify '… the another…'?

It isn't that other needs a specific position but rather that other has a specific meaning.
Very unusually in English, other can be either absolute or qualified, depending on the circumstances.
More unusually, the absolute or qualified uses can be pretty-much opposite.
Can we agree, the specific example given in the OQ is over-complicated? Is the original ‘In the background we can see other three people who are watching the film’ usefully different from ‘We see other three people…’ or, come to that, simply ‘other three’?
Am I mistaken in thinking other three can never stand alone but always requires qualification? Why, I know not.
Am I right in assuming ‘another/ any other/ some other/ that other/ the other/ this other/ those other/ what other/ which other…’ are all acceptable, as is ‘(any number) other’?
Am I correct in believing ‘how/ when/ where/ why’ can work the same way but don’t have to?
